# Angular JS fast resolve and slow controller page is empty while the data loads

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, spinner

I have a main.html like this . Where name card and system detail are going to remain as a constant and content will keep on changing depending upon the view .

```
        <div ui-view="nameCard"></div>
        <div ui-view="systemDetail"></div>
        <div ui-view="content"></div>
```

im using ui route for routing . when i switch from one view to other , resolve happens first (The page loads first here), followed by controller initialization and it loads the data . Due to the lazy controller , users are left to view at blank page for a while. Where and how should i add the Spinner logic so the user is left to view at the spinner till the data loads. When he clicks on a button i want to enable spinner before the resolve happens and hide the spinner after the post has happened successfully .shoud i ass it in the main.html or i should add it in the content page

Answer (score 0):

You can enable spinner on state change like this

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
  // add show spinner code here
});
```

and disable when content load

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
  // add hide spinner code here
});
```

Comment: The problem here is state change is so fast . I want the spinner to be enabled when the route starts and to be disabled only when the controller finishes sending the data to the dom .

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have below HTML

```
<div class="icon-spinner" ng-show="displaySpin">
```

you can bind the `$rootscope` variable for spinner display in the function when  the route change happens:

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart",
     function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
         $rootScope.displaySpin = true;
     });
```

When the page gets loaded and the controller gets initialized, 
do this in the first line of controller:

```
$rootScope.displaySpin = false;
```

Comment: Karun , the route is so fast . I want the Spin to keep on running for route change and also while the controller fetches the data . I want it only to stop after the controller finishes loading data

Comment: Yes my dear, So you can set the value to false inside the success callback (`then`) function of the data-fetching call

Comment: should i add the icon-spinner inside the main.html or in my corresponding html content

Comment: it will go most probably in Main html , and not inside the different Views.

Comment: Will it affect for all state changes ? . I want this to happen only for particular state changes

Comment: Well, you have the callback function with `toState` parameter, which can be utilized in your case.